# Building gRPC and openssl as dependency with cmake for msys2/mingw64 fails with undefined references

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, grpc, msys2

I'm trying to build the grpc helloworld example with changed file tree structure and my own CMakeLists.txt with msys2/mingw64. I want to build grpc from sources as a static library using add_subdirectory and build grpc's dependencies recursevily from sources as well.

Doing that I was getting linking errors with undefined references. After some research it seems that boringssl has problems with building in msys2/mingw64 or at least the way boringssl is included in grpc's repo isn't compatible with msys2/mingw64.

Since the grpc package in msys2 is built using openssl as dependency I decided to build openssl from sources during the build and let grpc statically link to that. I hope it is enough to just clone grpc without the boringssl submodule.

I was able to succesfully link and run the example when openssl was linked dynamically to libssl.dll.a. However when I try to link to static openssl build I'm getting undefined references errors again.`grpc_test2_server.exe

This are the linking errors I'm getting:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -g  @CMakeFiles\grpc_test2_server.rsp -o grpc_test2_server.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgrpc_test2_server.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o): in function `addr_strings':    
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:208: undefined reference to `__imp_getnameinfo'     
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:220: undefined reference to `gai_strerrorW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o): in function `BIO_lookup_ex':   
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:731: undefined reference to `gai_strerrorW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): in function `BIO_sock_error':  
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_sock.c:99: undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'       
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): in function `BIO_gethostbyname':
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_sock.c:113: undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'   
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o): in function `BIO_listen':     
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:217: undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'     
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o): in function `BIO_accept_ex':  
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:290: undefined reference to `__imp_accept'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_get_prov_info':
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1281: undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1289: undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_cert_get_fname':
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1329: undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1335: undefined reference to `__imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_open_store': 
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1400: undefined reference to `__imp_CertOpenStore'     
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_list_certs': 
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1432: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1435: undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1443: undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_find_cert':  
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1455: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFindCertificateInStore'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1459: undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_find_key':   
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1559: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1561: undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1593: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: third-party/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o): in function `capi_load_ssl_client_cert':
C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1720: undefined reference to `__imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1740: undefined reference to `__imp_CertDuplicateCertificateContext'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1754: undefined reference to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PatVax\Workspace\cpp\grpc_test2\build-debug\third-party\openssl_build/../../../third-party/openssl/engines/e_capi.c:1756: undefined reference to `__imp_CertCloseStore'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt that I'm currently using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(grpc_test2 C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_CSHARP_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_PHP_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_PYTHON_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_NODE_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_RUBY_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_OBJC_EXT OFF)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_OBJC_PLUGIN OFF)

set(_gRPC_BASELIB_LIBRARIES libws2_32 libcrypt32)

include(ProcessorCount)
ProcessorCount(N)

set(OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/openssl)
set(OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/openssl_build)
set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/openssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)
set(MSYS_SHELL ${MSYS2_ROOT}/msys2_shell.cmd)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
  set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${MSYS_SHELL} -mingw64 -no-start -here -defterm -c 
    "${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/Configure --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} --release -static no-shared mingw64")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
  set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${MSYS_SHELL} -mingw64 -no-start -here -defterm -c 
    "${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/Configure --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} --debug -static no-shared mingw64")
else()
  set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${MSYS_SHELL} -mingw64 -no-start -here -defterm -c 
    "${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/Configure --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} -static no-shared mingw64")
endif()

add_custom_target(OpenSSL_Configured
  COMMAND ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}
  BYPRODUCTS ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}/Makefile
  DEPENDS ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/Configure
  COMMENT "OpenSSL is configuring")

add_custom_target(OpenSSL_Built
  COMMAND ${MSYS_SHELL} -mingw64 -no-start -here -defterm -c "make -j${N}"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}
  BYPRODUCTS ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}/libssl.a ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}/libcrypto.a
  DEPENDS OpenSSL_Configured
  COMMENT "OpenSSL is building")

add_custom_target(OpenSSL_Installed
  COMMAND ${MSYS_SHELL} -mingw64 -no-start -here -defterm -c "make install"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_BINARY_DIR}
  BYPRODUCTS ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.dll.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.dll.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.dll ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.dll
  DEPENDS OpenSSL_Built
  COMMENT "OpenSSL is installing")

add_custom_target(OpenSSL DEPENDS OpenSSL_Installed COMMENT "OpenSSL is ready")

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(OpenSSL::SSL STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL)

add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::Crypto OpenSSL)

add_library(ssl STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET ssl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a)
set_property(TARGET ssl PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(ssl OpenSSL)

add_library(crypto STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET crypto PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a)
set_property(TARGET crypto PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(crypto OpenSSL)

set(_gRPC_SSL_LIBRARIES ssl crypto)
set(_gRPC_SSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(third-party/grpc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/grpc)

get_filename_component(hw_proto "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobufs/helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)

set(hw_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.cc")
set(hw_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.h")
set(hw_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hw_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.h")
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND protobuf::protoc
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${hw_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${hw_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_library(hw_grpc_proto
  ${hw_grpc_srcs}
  ${hw_grpc_hdrs}
  ${hw_proto_srcs}
  ${hw_proto_hdrs})
target_link_libraries(hw_grpc_proto grpc++ grpc++_reflection libprotobuf)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_server server.cpp)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_client client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_server grpc++ grpc++_reflection libprotobuf hw_grpc_proto)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_client grpc++ grpc++_reflection libprotobuf hw_grpc_proto)
```

My directory structure looks like the following:

[image]

- grpc is cloned with all submodules without boringssl
- openssl is cloned with all submodules
- protobufs contains the .proto files that are being compiled during the build process
- Contents of the .cpp files are identical to those in the helloworld example in the grpc repo

What could be the reason of my problems? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT3: <strike>I've actually realized a big blunder here. You can't link against the `ws2_32.lib` as it was built with MSVC and not MinGW. However the issue to your problem stems from here.</strike>

I feel like a donkey, but apparently **newer versions of MSYS2/MinGW** should be able to link against these static libraries. So the following solution is worth a try.

---

EDIT: After some digging in I think I found the reason why MSVC is supported and mingw is not. The reason why you're having issues is because they are most likely using `#pragma` to link their libraries (this is a MSVC specific feature).

Try additionaly linking to this library: `ws2_32` (maybe the 64 bit version is called `ws2_64`) - (more precisely you want to link against winsock2 64 bit version)

EDIT2: They are all named `ws2_32` and the `#pragma` picks the right one for you, i.e. the only thing different is the path to the correct SDK

---

Based on **[this official github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18657)**. The `GRPC` team does not support MinGW for Windows builds.

They describe the same issue that you are describing and they also have a suggestion on how to fix `boringssl` to work i.e.

- By **[applying this patch](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-grpc)** and
- by building `boringssl` with the following define `OPENSSL_NO_ASM`.

Long story short, I would switch to MSVC on Windows if I were you - I don't see a reason why not to use it if your target platform is Windows anyway.

EDIT: However if you are still persistent on using MinGW then maybe to maybe get you closer to how to fix your issue I would maybe point out that **[`gai_strerrorW` is a function defined in ws2tcpip.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrorw)**

Comment: The reason I need it to work with mingw is licensing. MSVC comes with Visual Studio and I wouldn't be able to use it in business environment without additional costs. Other than that the patch you linked is not there anymore I guess. I see there only the PKGBUILD of the grpc msys2 package. I tried setting OPENSSL_NO_ASM but it results in errors at the compilation stage.

Comment: If you get just the build tools then it is free to use. The issue is the Visual Studio (licence wise). Other then that, link against the winsock2 libs and make sure you have the latest mingw - it should resolve the issues.